# If my trip is cancelled, can I use my US B2 visa later?

Tags: visas, usa, b1-b2-visas

I'm planning to apply for a US B2 travel visa and stay there for 7 days. I have done all my preparation and ready to go for the interview. (I understand they now may give people 10 years grant).

However, there is a chance that I might need to cancel my trip later on and decide to go to the US later (e.g. half a year or a year later before the visa expires, and also stay 7 days).

If this happens, what should I do to inform the change of my situation? Do I

- submit a new plan before my new trip?
- Or do I just need to re-apply and get a new visa while the existing one is still valid?

(I don't want them to think that I'm making a false representation).

Comment: I would say, just let them know that your trip may be postponed.

Comment: How do I let them know then? Submit a letter, or phone them? Is there any website to say which number I should phone?

Comment: During the interview.

Comment: This indicates to me that, if someone applies a US visa, they will need to volunteer to say their trip may be postponed (just to be on the safe side...)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Trips are postponed and cancelled all the time. The counselor will decide whether or not you qualify for a visa at the time of the interview. USA visas do not guarantee entry. They only give you permission to board your flight and apply for admission at a port of entry. The final decision is made by an immigration officer.

A change of plans or a cancellation does not invalidate your visa. You do not need to reapply for another visa if the purpose of your trip conforms to the conditions of your valid visa. It is unlikely but you may be asked at the PoE why your original plans were cancelled/postponed.